# Update multiple conditions array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this data :

```js
{
  'id': '1',
  'object': [
     {'code': 'a'},
     {'code': 'b'},
     {'code': 'c'}
  ]
}
```

And this query :

```js
db.test.update({
    'id': '1',
    'object': {
        '$elemMatch': {
            '$or': [
                {'code': 'b'},
                {'code': 'c'}
            ]
        }
    }
},
    {'$set':{'object.$.test':'ok'}}
)
```

Documents can contain one of these codes, both or none.
It works well with documents with one condition fulfilled.

In the case if there are 2 codes in the document, only the first one is updated :
I want to update both of them (code: 'b' AND code: 'c')

```js
{
  'id': '1',
  'object': [
     {'code': 'a', 'test': 'ok'},
     {'code': 'b'}
  ]
}
```

This is what I want :

```js
{
  'id': '1',
  'object': [
     {'code': 'a', 'test': 'ok'},
     {'code': 'b', 'test': 'ok'}
  ]
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: the `$` positional will update first matching element, for multiple elements update use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of `$[identifier]` update and pass the conditions in `arrayFilters` since `$` will update only a single record as pointed by [@turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal)

```
db.collection.update({
  "id": "1",
  "object.code": {
    "$in": [
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "object.$[elem].code": "ok"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.code": {
        "$in": [
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
},
)
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QAAgW5mtvqa)